# Ionic 4 read SMS plugin for OTP Verification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing the ionic4 app, to auto verification or whenever I will get SMS my app has to read that message. for this I used 'Cordova plugin add Cordova-plugin-SMS' but it is not working. i declared 'declare var window: any; and declare var SMS: any;' nothing has worked. it showing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rjfun.cordova.sms.SMSPlugin" in Android, in the web while developing it showing " TypeError: Cannot read property 'listSMS' of undefined". can any one help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

There is one plugin which could solve your problem. Named cordova-plugin-sms-receive.
This will help to read sms when any phone received and you can do whatever you want.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms-receive

Answer (score 0):

That [plugin](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin) enables sending an SMS from the app, not receiving an SMS.

To get data from an SMS to your app, you could pass it as args using deeplinks. This would required the user to tap a link in the SMS. I am not aware of a way to have SMS data fed to your app automatically, and I would think it is not possible as it would be a security risk.

A custom URL scheme is the simplest way to do that (e.g. `mycoolapp://some-path?p1=data1&p2=data2`.

[App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/) (Android > 6.0) and [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) (iOS > 9.0) are more powerful but may be unnecessary and are not as well supported. It really depends on your use case.

Ionic has a [community maintained plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) for this which I use and does the job, albeit with a workaround needed here and there. Branch.io's [plugin](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking) is also an option but I haven't used it.

Comment: do we have any ionic4 plugin to receive sms

Answer (score 0):

very nice question ... you need to use cordova plugin for that. Below are the

First you need to install Android Permission Ionic Native Plugin.
run these two commands first to install Android Permission Plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

Add android-permissions to your app's Module.

```
import { AndroidPermissions} from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

@NgModule({


  providers: [

    AndroidPermissions

  ]

})
export class AppModule { }
```

Check permissions on page

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';


export class HomePage {
constructor(public androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { }



ionViewWillEnter()
{

this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_SMS).then(
  success => console.log('Permission granted'),
err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_SMS)
);

this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_SMS]);
}
}
```

After allowing Read SMS permission now you need to install cordova-plugin-sms. Run this command for install it.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sms-plugin

npm install @ionic-native/sms
```

and in your page while reading SMS -

place this in top before declare class

```
declare var SMS:any;
```

place below inside class

```
ionViewDidEnter()
    {

    this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
    if(SMS) SMS.startWatch(()=>{
               console.log('watching started');
            }, Error=>{
           console.log('failed to start watching');
       });

      document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', (e:any)=>{
           var sms = e.data;
           console.log(sms);

           });

        });
    }
```

Comment: Dose this work in ionic 6 capacitor,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Ionic/Cordova plugin for Auto OTP verification and this will not ask the user for SMS read Permissions.

Plugin: https://github.com/hanatharesh2712/ionic-native-sms-retriever-plugin-master

Demo App: https://github.com/hanatharesh2712/sms-plugin-test

Comment: Can this be used with capacitor?

Comment: @AdamMendoza Sorry, Not sure about the capacitor, but, If you can use other Cordova plugins then you can use this as well.